# Angular http response as error argument, even if the status is 200

Tags: angular, spring-boot, frontend, backend

So i am trying to do a "GET" request from my spring boot back-end and i receive the response but the picture is coming as error argument. I can use the error argument and use the picture on the website but i still get as error even if the status is 200.

Backend code:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins="http://localhost:4200")
@GetMapping(
  path = "/images/path-variable/{name}"
)
static public ResponseEntity<String> getImageWithMediaType(@PathVariable String name) throws IOException, Exception {
    System.out.println("/images/" + name + ".jpg");
    File tempFile = new File("/home/ninhow/Desktop/antons-skafferi-front-back/backend/src/main/resources/images/restaurant_1280x853.jpg");

    return ResponseEntity.ok(CodecBase64.encode(tempFile, true));
}
```

In angular i do a request from my service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
 })
export class GetImageService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

getImage(){
  return this.http.get<any>("http://localhost:8080/images/path-variable/restaurant_1280x853");
  }
}
```

The component function where i use to receive the response and use it:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
image: any;

 constructor(private service: GetImageService, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
 ngOnInit() {
  this.getHeaderImage();
 }

 getHeaderImage(){
    this.service.getImage().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
    this.image = "data:image/jpeg;base64" + data;
 }, error=>{
    var response = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + (error as any).error.text
    console.log(error);
    this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(response);
    });
 }

}
```

Basically what i am trying to do is to send a picture from my back-end so i can use in my front-end without errors:

html file for the component:

```
<p>header works!</p>
<div>
   <img [src]="image" alt="">
</div>
```

Browser console error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gumCw.png

[image]

After editing my getImage function with a overload the function looks like this:

```
  getImage(){
return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/images/path- 
  variable/restaurant_1280x853", {
  responseType: "text"
  });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Read the error message. It tells what's wrong. The HttpClient tries toparse your base64 text as JSON, because you're not using the correct get() overload. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get

Comment: Am i supposed to add options on the getImage function on my service?

Comment: Yes. You want to use the overload that returns an Observable<string>. Find it in the documentation, and pass the options that are necessary for this overload to be selected.

Comment: So i resolved the error but i get new errors, i get the base64 on the response... the only problem is that i get "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large"

Comment: As for every question asking about an error, you need to provide the relevant code, the exact and complete error message/stack trace, and tell when, where and how this error appears.

Comment: Sorry, i updated the question with the new function change in the bottom.

Comment: I also solved this issue by adding "'data:image/jpg;base64,'" to the sanitizer but i dont understand why that helped.

Comment: I found all the anwsers, the result will be up in a couple of hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i found a solution to my problem, with the help of the comments above.
So the first part of the solution was to change my get overload in my `getImage()` function to this:

```
getImage(){
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/images/path-variable/restaurant_1280x853", {
      responseType: "text"
   });
}
```

i had to add a `responseType:"text"` as a option since it was expecting a json and it was receiving a base64 string.

Later i had a problem with:
[image]

My solution to this was to add `'data:image/jpg;base64,'` to the sanitizer, i have not figured out yet why this works but it solved the problem. My best guess is that I am telling the header that it is a base64 string.

final function:

```
  getHeaderImage(){
    this.service.getImage().subscribe(data => {
      this.image = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('data:image/jpg;base64,' + data);    
    }, error=>{
    console.log(error);
    });
  }
```

My page was loading a null result at the beginning, i dont understand how since the function is called on `ngOnInit()` my solution to this was to add `*ngIf="image"` to the html file, what i am basically telling is: If there is a image loaded, then use the source otherwise... don't.

final html:

```
<div>
    <img *ngIf="image" [src]="image">

</div>
```